# How to call a function within a string for a title

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that produces 4 images (Below I only include 2 as an example of output). I have another function that determines what % cat or dog the picture is and I would like to call that function in the title of the following code

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Mpic():
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,30))

    path = r"data/dogscats1/pupper"
    path1 = r"data/dogscatspeople/test1"
    path2 = r"data/dogscatspeople/test1"
    path3 = r"data/dogscats1/pupper"

    imgpath1 =  path + "/cat.jpg"
    imgpath2 =  path1 + "/1.jpg"
    imgpath3 =  path2 + "/2.jpg"
    imgpath4 =  path3 + "/dog.jpg"

    img1 = cv2.imread(imgpath1, 1)
    img2 = cv2.imread(imgpath2, 1)
    img3 = cv2.imread(imgpath3, 1)
    img4 = cv2.imread(imgpath4, 1)

    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img4 = cv2.cvtColor(img4, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    titles = ['Kitty', '% Cat = , Dog % = ','% Cat = , Dog % =', 'Pupper']
    images = [img1, img2, img3, img4]

    for i in range(4):
        plt.subplot(4,2,i+1)
        plt.imshow(images[i])
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.yticks([])

    plt.show()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Mpic()
```

[image]

This is the original function that calls the array:

```
def pred_datsci(file_path):
    prev_precompute = learn.precompute
    learn.precompute = False
    try:
        trn_tfms, val_tfms = tfms_from_model(arch,sz)
        test_img = open_image(file_path)
        im = val_tfms(test_img)
        pred =  learn.predict_array(im[None])
        class_index = (np.exp(pred))
        class_index1 = np.argmax(np.exp(pred))
        print(class_index*100)
        return data.classes[class_index1] 
    finally:
        learn.precompute = prev_precompute
```

Which can return something along the lines of:

```
pred_datsci(f"data/dogscats1/valid/dogs/12501.jpg")
```

[image]

I want it to call it in the form of something like this:

```
 titles = [ cat % = pred_datsci(f"data/dogscats1/valid/cats/cat.1.jpg"),"etc"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 titles = [ "cat % = {}".format(pred_datsci("data/dogscats1/valid/cats/cat.1.jpg")),"etc"]
```